# How do you name the functions in a Swift Protocol?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

When I declare a Protocol in Swift like this, say for a network module:

```
Protocol MyNetworkProtocol {
    func reportError(error: Int)   // <-- do you add prefix for this?
}
```

How do you name the functions inside a protocol? Do you add prefix for it?

I ask this because if I name the function as shown above, the caller would be like:

```
class MyClass: MyNetworkProtocol {

    // some code for MyClass

    func reportError(error: Int) {
        // some code to handle it
    }
}
```

If I view the code in `MyClass` solely, `reportError` cannot be identified as a the implementation of a protocol of another class immediately (unless I add some comment in the code).

I am thinking to name the functions in protocols like this:

```
Protocol MyNetworkProtocol {
    func myNetworkProtocol_reportError(error: Int)   
}
```

So that in `MyClass`, I can quickly know it's a implementation of a protocol for a certain class. Is this necessary? Do I misunderstand some concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. Instead segregate the protocol methods into a separate extension.

```
class MyClass {
}

extension MyClass: MyNetworkProtocol {
    func reportError(error: Int) {
        // some code to handle it
    }
}
```

Comment: I always do this if I implement a protocol like UITableView.... UICollectionView.... etc.

Answer (score -1):

In protocol function start by protocol name with arguments of protocol class & additional

```
Protocol MyNetworkProtocol {

    func myNetworkProtocol(_ myNetwork: MyNetworkProtocol, _reportErrot: Int)

    }
}
```

Like this function will help to debug easily

Comment: The power of this idiom is that if your class needs to deal with multiple objects calling back to it, it can tell which object the message originated from.

Comment: We need to handle to avoid errors. If that will help full you can try that. or else no need to pass a class argument in protocol